# How to shift binary into a shift register (serial in, parallel out) sequentially

Tags: arduino-mega, c++

I'm trying to make a continuity tester at work where I connect the input and output of a harness into a test fixture powered by an Arduino. This tester tests whether the position of the connects are pinned correctly.

Here is the diagram of my initial idea:

[image]

From one end of the connector (the output in the diagram), I want to shift in a binary that is in the power of 2. For instance, shifting in `0001`, check for continuity by reading the 75HC165 (parallel in, serial out), then clear the register and then shift in `0010`, and then `0100` and so on. For a correctly pinned harness, the write and read binary subtraction will be zero.

Here is my loop that attempts to perform the above:

```
void loop() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    reset_SIPO_register();
    shift_SIPO(pow(2,i));
    delay(2000);
    shift_SIPO(0x00));
    check_continuity(); // not implemented yet
  }
}

void reset_SIPO_register() {
  digitalWrite(reset_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(reset_pin, HIGH);
}

void shift_SIPO(int sequence) {
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, LOW);
  shiftOut(data_pin, clock_pin, MSBFIRST, sequence);
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, HIGH);
}
```

I am testing this concept on a breadboard with LEDs and the above kind of works. However, the LED is lit up one at a time and they don't turn off, not following the binary.

Is there something I'm missing here? thanks!

Comment: yes, you are missing the full schematic diagram and complete code from your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `pow()`. This is a function that works with floating point
numbers. It is roughly equivalent (for y > 0) to

```cpp
double pow(double x, double y)
{
    return exp(y * log(x));
}
```

As all transcendental functions, its implementation is prone to rounding
errors. It is not even guaranteed to give you the “correctly” rounded
version of the exact (i.e. infinite precision) result. In fact, very few
floating point functions give this guarantee.

As an example, if you compute `pow(2, i)` for i = 3, you get
7.9999980926513671875. This is 4 [ULPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) smaller than the exact value.
Passing this number to `shift_SIPO()` implicitly converts it to an
`int`, and this conversion always rounds to zero. Thus you get 7, i.e.
`0b0111`.

What you want is an integer, exact implementation of `pow(2, i)`. It
turns out this is quite simple: Take the integer 1 in binary, then shift
it `i` times to the left. That is

```cpp
shift_SIPO(1 << i);
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked!